# Tablelayout with in scrollview in android

Tags: android-layout

Please help How to handle(work) with a table layout .Now i want to place table layout elements within the ScrollView... how to workout it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this... I am adding the xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"             android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button1"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button2"/>       
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button3"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button4"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button5"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button6"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button7"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button8"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button9"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button10"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button11"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button12"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button13"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button14"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button15"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button16"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button17"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button18"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button19"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button20"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button21"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button22"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button23"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button24"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button25"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button26"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```